# recorrer un fichero leyendo linea a linea con una condicion de parada

Tags: python

Tengo un fichero login.txt con esta estructura

```
DirServer
Usuario
Passwd
RutaDescarga
RutaServer
Patron
#
DirServer
Usuario
Passwd
RutaDescarga
RutaServer
Patron
#
DirServer
Usuario
Passwd
RutaDescarga
RutaServer
Patron
```

¿Como puedo recorrer el fichero linea a linea? ¿Como se puede establecer la 
    condicion de leer hasta el #?

mi codigo lo tenia asi porque solo tenia un bloque

```
DirServer:
Usuario:
Passwd:
RutaDescarga:
RutaServer:
Patron:

with open("login.txt") as fichero:
    dirServer = fichero.readline().split(":")[1].strip()
    usuario = fichero.readline().split(":")[1].strip()
    passwd = fichero.readline().split(":")[1].strip()
```

Y me han negado cortar lo que viene detras de :  por posibles fallos y me 
han cambiado mi idea si mi fichero login.txt ahora es asi

```
dirServer 10.0.0.3
usuario Administrador
passwd ##########
#
dirServer 10.0.0.4
usuario Administrador
passwd ##########
#
dirServer 10.0.0.5
usuario Administrador
passwd #########
#
```

Comment: Puedes aclarar un poco más el contenido de `login.txt` que tienes ahora? ¿Las cadenas como `DirServer` , `Usuario`, aparecen así tal cual y después de ellas el valor correspondiente? ¿Separado por dos puntos o por espacio o de qué modo? ¿O bien no aparecen tal cual sino que en realidad son directamente los valores? (Quiero decir, la primera línea por ejemplo en lugar de traer algo como `DirServer: 192.1.7.2` trae directamente algo como `192.1.7.2`?)

Comment: Y no está claro si debes procesar todos los bloques delimitados por el `#` o solo el primero de ellos.

Comment: se puede cambiar un poco tu archivo config? para usar ConfigParser

Comment: si claro, puedo hacer las modificaciones precisas, la única condición es dejarlo automatizado

Comment: tengo que procesar todos los bloques, el # lo puse yo pensando en separar los bloques

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes usar [ConfigParser](https://docs.python.org/2/library/configparser.html) para los archivos de configuracion, aqui un ejemplo:

**login.txt**

```
[server_1]
dirServer = 10.0.0.4
usuario =Administrador
passwd =##########
[server_2]
dirServer=10.0.0.5
usuario=Administrador
passwd=#########
```

**config.py**

```
#!/usr/bin/python
from configparser import ConfigParser
def config_server(section='server_1' , filename='login.txt'):
    parser = ConfigParser()
    parser.read(filename)
    section_params = {}
    if parser.has_section(section):
        params = parser.items(section)
        for param in params:
            section_params[param[0]] = param[1]
    else:
        raise Exception('Seccion {0} no encontrada en el archivo{1}'.format(section, filename))

    return section_params
```

para obtener los parametros basta con llamarla de la siguiente forma:

```
config_server() # retornara resultados server_1 en el archivo login.txt
config_server("server_2") # retornara resultados del server_2 en archivo login.txt
config_server("server_3" , "config.ini") # retornara resultados del server_3 en archivo config.ini
```

---

otra opcion es de la siguiente forma :

```
#!/usr/bin/python
from configparser import ConfigParser
config = ConfigParser.RawConfigParser(allow_no_value=True)
config.readfp('login.txt')
config.get("server_1", "dirServer")
```

Comment: y mi pregunta es, en el caso que me has puesto hay dos servidores solo,, y si hay mas? yo tenia pensado un bucle e iterar con lo que me devuelve

Comment: no entiendo a que te refieres

Comment: la idea es tner un archivo de configuracion (en tu caso login.txt) donde puedas leer a donde quieras conectarte y hacer una operacion, es esta forma leo el archivo de configuracion y me traigo el segmento que necesito puede ser [server1] [server2] , otros

Answer (score 1):

Aunque la estructura de tu fichero es lo bastante sencilla como para poder implementar fácilmente un bucle que lo recorra y lo vaya procesando, ya que en un comentario admites que se pueda modificar el formato del fichero lo suyo sería usar un formato estándar para el que haya disponbles herramientas automáticas de *parseo*.

Los típicos formatos usados para configuración son JSON o YAML. También tenemos TOML, mucho menos usado, pero que se ha ganado el favor de Python, ya que será el formato "oficial" para la configuración de paquetes a ser publicados en PyPi.

Un ejemplo de como quedaría tu fichero de configuración con YAML:

```
servidores:
- dirServer: 10.0.0.3
  usuario: Administrador
  passwd: "##########"
- dirServer: 10.0.0.4
  usuario: Administrador
  passwd: "##########"
- dirServer: 10.0.0.5
  usuario: Administrador
  passwd: "#########"
```

Para leer ese fichero necesitas tener instalado el paquete `pyyaml` (`pip install pyyaml`), y la lectura sería tan simple como:

```
import yaml
with open("login.yaml") as f:
  data = yaml.safe_read(f)
```

Si prefieres el formato TOML, el fichero `login.toml` tendría esta estructura:

```
[[servidores]]
dirServer = "10.0.0.3"
usuario = "Administrador"
passwd = "##########"

[[servidores]]
dirServer = "10.0.0.4"
usuario = "Administrador"
passwd = "##########"

[[servidores]]
dirServer = "10.0.0.5"
usuario = "Administrador"
passwd = "#########"
```

Para leerlo es igual de simple, pero necesitas el paquete `toml`(`pip install toml`):

```
import toml
with open("conf.toml") as f:
  data = toml.load(f)
```

Cualquiera de las dos formas al final te da lugar al mismo resultado en la variable `data`. Esa variable será un diccionario que tendrá la clave `"servidores"`, y dentro de ella la lista con la información que necesitas. Así:

```
>>> print(data["servidores"])
[{'dirServer': '10.0.0.3', 'passwd': '##########', 'usuario': 'Administrador'},
 {'dirServer': '10.0.0.4', 'passwd': '##########', 'usuario': 'Administrador'},
 {'dirServer': '10.0.0.5', 'passwd': '#########', 'usuario': 'Administrador'}]
```

Esto ya lo procesas con un bucle como es habitual en python. Por ejemplo así:

```
for servidor in data["servidores"]:
   conectarse(servidor["dirServer"], servidor["usuario"], servidor["passwd"])
```

**Nota** El formato YAML parece más simple a la hora de editar a mano el fichero de configuración. Sin embargo la lectura de YAML es más complicada que la de TOML (porque, aunque en este ejemplo no lo estamos usando, YAML tiene muchas más posibilidades y mucha más flexibilidad, si bien en la práctica casi nunca se usa esta potencia).

La biblioteca para parsear YAML ocupa mucho más (y es más lenta) que la de TOML.

Comment: Vale he captado la idea. Yo python lo ejecuto en windows, se me olvido decirtelo ¿Que me recomiendas YAML o TOML?

Comment: Es un poco cuestión de gustos, aunque como dije TOML es más simple. Instalar toml supone solo 80Kb. Yaml ocupa 400Kb. Si no te preocupa el tamaño o la eficiencia, personalmente encuentro la sintaxis de los archivos .yaml más fácil de escribir, pues hay que tecleear menos. Por ejemplo no necesita comillas alrededor de los valores (IP, nombre de usuario), mientras que TOML sí, y en TOML tienes que repetir la cabecera `[[servidores]]` al inicio de cada "bloque". Pero vaya, son detalles menores.

Comment: He estado intentando lo que me has dicho y creo que me pierdo por ser muy complejo para mi. El fichero.txt lo voy a hacer con arrays de user

Comment: Me parece muy completo y por mi nivel lo hare con el manejo de arrays

Comment: @antoniop No entiendo a qué te refieres con arrays... En la solución tanto con yaml como con toml, al final también tienes un array. El objeto `data["servidores"]` es una lista (array) con los datos de cada servidor. Lo único que tiene de particular esta solución no está en el procesamiento de esos datos, que es una lista normal, sino en cómo son leidos, y sobre todo en cómo hay que escribirlos en el fichero de configuración para que se ajusten al estandar (yaml o toml)