# ¿ Como puedo leer un fichero txt desde un archivo python?

Tags: python, array

Necesito recorrer un fichero y extraer los valores de los arrays para guardarlos en unas variables

el **fichero login.txt** el que necesito recorrer tiene esta estructura:

```
# user=["dirServer","usuario","passwd","rutaServer","rutaDescarga","patron"]]

user1=["10.0.0.3","Root","*****","/usr/amat","C:\Users\becario2adm","yyyymmdd"]
user2=["10.0.0.4","Administrador","*******","/zzz","C:\Users\becario2adm","yyyy_mm_dd"]
user3=["10.0.0.5","Administrador","*******","/","C:\Users\becario2adm","yyyy_mm_dd"]


habia pensado leer ese fichero linea a linea con

while(mientras que la linea exista)
for linea in open('login.txt'):
    print (linea)
```

Comment: el fichero login.txt puede variar en un futuro y tener mas o menos users, habia pensado porner una marca de fin. Y aunque cambie el numero de usuarios, la condicion es la misma mientrras que no llege a fin, que lea todo lo demas.

Comment: Buenas, nos puedes mostrar algo de código y poder partir de ahí para ayudarte.

Comment: La sintaxis de ese fichero log que muestras es un mix entre sintaxis python (las variables `user1`, `user2` y `user3` se asignan como si fueran parte de un programa python), junto con cosas que no lo son, como la palabra `Fin` al final. Por otro parte te estás complicando a ti mismo el procesamiento de ese fichero, al elegir esa sintaxis rara. Usando formatos estándares como yaml o toml la lectura sería automática, mientras que de este modo tendrías que leer línea por línea y parsear esa sintaxis que has elegido de corchetes y comillas. Podrías usar `eval()`, pero es peligroso.

Comment: Reconsidera [la solución que te di en otra pregunta muy similar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/213528/7123) sobre el uso de yaml o toml. Es mucho más sencilla que esta otra que propones, creeme.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No tienes por qué complicarte la existencia reinventando la rueda. Ya existen formatos de fichero para guardar la información muy similares al que propones.

Por ejemplo, con un pequeño cambio de sintaxis en tu fichero `login.txt` puedes hacer que sea YAML válido. El único cambio necesario es usar comillas simples en lugar de dobles (para evitar tener problemas con el carácter `\` que aparece dentro de algunas de tus cadenas), y quitar las asignaciones a `user1`, `user2`, etc. cambiándolas por guiones.

Es decir, queda de esta otra forma:

```
# Contenido del fichero login.txt
- ['10.0.0.3','Root','*****','/usr/amat','C:\Users\becario2adm','yyyymmdd']
- ['10.0.0.4','Administrador','*******','/zzz','C:\Users\becario2adm','yyyy_mm_dd']
- ['10.0.0.5','Administrador','*******','/','C:\Users\becario2adm','yyyy_mm_dd']
```

Si estás dispuesto a admitir como válido este formato de entrada, que repito es prácticamente idéntico al que propones en la pregunta, entonces no necesitas programar ningún bucle para realizar la lectura.

Basta que tengas instalada la biblioteca `yaml` y hagas:

```
import yaml
with open("login.txt") as f:
  data = yaml.safe_load(f)
```

Y ya está. En `data` tienes una lista con tantos elementos como líneas tenía tu fichero. Cada elemento es otra lista cuyos elementos son la ip, nombre de usuario, clave, carpeta, etc.

Por ejemplo, el siguiente bucle itera sobre esa lista y muestra la IP y la carpeta

```
for elemento in data:
  print(elemento[0], elemento[3])
```

y sale

```
10.0.0.3 /usr/amat
10.0.0.4 /zzz
10.0.0.5 /
```

Supongo que no te será difícil adaptar este código para que en lugar de imprimir estas cosas por pantalla las use para hacer las conexiones ftp o lo que sea que quieras hacer con esa información.

Comment: justo eso es abufalia, voy a probar con yaml que lo deje instalado ayer

Comment: me da muchos errores eso que me has comentado

Comment: si, los he añadido en esta pregunta como puedes ver arriba

Comment: Parece que el fichero `login.txt` que le pasas a `safe_load()` no es yaml válido. ¿Has copiado tal cual el ejemplo que te he dado? Si no, ¿puedes poner el que estás usando? (Si tiene información confidencial modifícala, pero verifica que con las modificaciones sigue dándote error)

Comment: Se me paso ,disculpa, no metí login.txt con el formato que me dabas.

Comment: Ahora es cuando nose desarrollar mi idea en codigo, ¿Como podría extraer los valores de los arrays y usarlos en una funcion para conexion ftp en servidor?

Comment: Pues igual que los hemos extraido para imprimirlos. En `elemento[0]` tienes la IP, en `elemento[1]` el nombre de usuario, etc. Entiendo que la función para hacer la conexión FTP ya la tienes hecha, y que recibirá como parámetros esos datos ¿no?

Comment: ya pero me refiero como puedo decir el elemento0 = dirServer

Comment: No tienes que decir eso, en todo caso sería `dirServer = elemento[0]`, no? Creo que mejor abres otra pregunta, pero esta duda me parece muy básica... ¿nunca has usado listas en python?

Comment: Abro otra pregunta, no hay problema. LLevo un mes con python, soy nuevo en este lenguaje y mas o menos voy cogiendo conceptos, (mis conocimientos son de Linux y php y no puedo plasmarlos en Python y me siento un poco perdido)

Comment: Abri la otra pregunta por si pudieras hecharme una mano, creo que entendiste mi idea ¿verdad?